# Importrange doesn't work when last digit is 0 in a number

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, importrange

When I import 35% discount from my [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10UIQseUBLhJ3BRI-pOqROvYtSbWNCRrj054LGH0peDE/edit?usp=sharing), it works; but when I want to import 40% discount, it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE(
 "10UIQseUBLhJ3BRI-pOqROvYtSbWNCRrj054LGH0peDE", "All Books!B2:L")), 
 "where Col11 contains '40' limit 10", 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dear @player0 The number value formatted as text. that's why it doesn't calculate :)

Answer (score 1):

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10UIQseUBLhJ3BRI-pOqROvYtSbWNCRrj054LGH0peDE","All Books!B2:L"),"Select * where Col11 contains '4' limit 10",1)`

---

**Screenshot 40% discount books**
[image: Screenshot]

---

The reason that `where Col11 contains '35'` does not translate to `where Col11 contains '40'` is that the **real** value of the relevant cell in Col11 is 0.35 or 0.4; the cells are merely formatted as percentage. So, there *are* cells that contain "35", but no cells that contains "40"; OTOH there are cells that contain "4".

So the formula looks for cells containing "4" rather than "40".

**Q:** Why does the formula provided by @player0 work, even though it refers to `where Col11 contains '40'`?
**A:** That formula also includes `to_text` which converts the numeric value to a text value. In this case, it converts 40% to 40.

Comment: You're right dear @Tendinoz, but what about when I want to sort out the data 40% and 45% separately?

Comment: @Mahabub There is an old Australian saying, “Life wasn’t meant to be easy” ;) There are many options, but player0’s ‘to_text’ shows why it was such a good answer. It would definitely be my go-to solution.